# iOS ARKit4 - how to fix white balance for the ARCamera?

Tags: ios, arkit, swift5, avcapturesession, arcamera

I have an app that generates point cloud from multiple `ARFrame`. It appears that the camera used to capture the image has dynamic white balance, and can change it in the middle of a capture session.

**How do I configure ARView, ARSession, or ARCamera to force it to lock white balance for the duration of the session?**

I have access to the following parameters, but do not see anything related to white balance.

```
var arView: ARView!
let session: ARSession = arView.session
var sampleFrame: ARFrame = session.currentFrame! 
let camera = sampleFrame.camera


func configureSessionAndRun() {

        arView.automaticallyConfigureSession = false
        let configuration = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()
        
        configuration.sceneReconstruction = .meshWithClassification
        configuration.frameSemantics = .smoothedSceneDepth
        configuration.planeDetection = [.horizontal, .vertical]
        
        configuration.environmentTexturing = .automatic
        
        arView.session.run(configuration)
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

There are only two AR View's properties that could help, but they are just gettable, not settable:

```
let frame = arView.session.currentFrame

frame?.camera.exposureDuration         // { get }
frame?.camera.exposureOffset           // { get }
```